# is there any way to reduce PNG size?

Tags: android, png, image-compression

as 
`bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, out);
//here 50 will not work as PNG is lossless`

how to reduce .png image size?
also just coping to external location from drawable make file size increase by 5 to 10 times?

```
Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);

String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Comment: What is a point of doing that? (coping from drawable to external)

Comment: @selvin there may a case where you want to put all you drawable PNG in users folder such that user can use those in some other apps...:)

Answer (score 5):

1)If your pngs are pre defined you can use [tiny png](https://tinypng.com/) service to have very small pngs. The service is reducing png size about 60 percents, without any noticable change.
2)If your pngs are created/get during runtime, try to use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) method. With this method you can create small size pngs.

In the method

`bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream)`;

100 is ignored in case of PNG. Because it's lossless. Instead you can use

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outStream);
```

This one will give you small size and will compress faster.

Comment: But it will give you a JPG, right? Even if you keep the same file name and extension (.png), the data from that compress call will be a JPG format.

Comment: If you use Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG - YES.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I will still answer for any future seekers.
Android's Bitmap class is pretty limited in compressing PNG. It only creates PNG-32 with limited optimization. The aapt program, that packages your apk file, does optimize the PNG file. Therefore when you are uncompressing and reading your PNG file into a bitmap, and then compressing it with the the bitmap class, you are getting a much larger file.
You can use the [pngj](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pngj/wikis/Overview.wiki) library, which supports much better compression of PNG files.
But based on your description you don't seem to edit the files in the app, you just copy from the resources to the card, so all you need to do is include the PNG file in the `raw` folder, and retrieve a stream to it by calling `openRawResource()`, and copying it directly to card. You may further optimize the original PNG file, by using [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.com) before including it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to stick strictly to PNG? Bitmap.compressFormat.JPEG would be able to compress much more.

The only way to reduce PNG file size is to reduce the PNG image dimensions to something smaller. I don't think that's straight forward with pure Android, but there are image libraries you can use for this.

You can also write it yourself by creating a new Bitmap object and manually reading from original using getPixels(...), pocessing them to downscale, and writing the new one. But I would not recommend that, resizing can be tricky to get working properly with anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping the quality of bitmap as it is. is it necessary for you? if not so, you can reduce size as `bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, outStream);` . here the 50 is the quality of bitmap being compressed. another option is to use `Bitmap.Option` Before Loading the Bitmap into Memory.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = 3;
    try{
        mBitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPhotoPath.replace("file://" , ""), options);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new OutOfMemoryError("Device Out of Memory, can't obtain Bitmap");
    }
```

if you just want to get the size of Bitmap, make `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true`. it's helpful to prevent runtime crashes of application

for more information on Bitmap loading and compression refer to the developer docs https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Bitmap class is not that much helpful compressing PNG. It only creates PNG-32 with limited optimization. The **aapt**, does optimize the PNG file. hence, when you are uncompressing and reading your PNG file into a bitmap, and then compressing it with the bitmap class, you are getting a much larger file.
You can use the [pngj](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj) library, which supports better compression and optimization of PNG files.
According to your description you don't seem to edit the files in the app, you may just copy from the resources to the card, so all you need to do is include the PNG file in the *raw* folder, and retrieve a stream to it by calling **openRawResource()** method, and copying it directly to card. You may further optimize the original PNG file using [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) before including it in your app.

Comment: CompressFormat.PNG will ignore the quality 50 setting.